# Why many BibTeX styles under LyX don't work?

Tags: bibtex, errors, lyx

I'm testing a well-formatted `bib` file with a single entry,

```
@misc{various_authors_main_2015,
    title = {Main {Page}},
    copyright = {Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License},
    url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Main_Page&oldid=647785249},
    language = {en},
    urldate = {2015-03-16},
    journal = {Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia},
    author = {{Various authors}},
    month = feb,
    year = {2015},
    note = {Page Version ID: 647785249}
}
```

using the various styles available from [`texlive-publishers`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/texlive-publishers) and [`texlive-bibtex-extra`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/texlive-bibtex-extra).

I have two issues (I did Tools->Reconfigure, and restarted before testing):

1. Not all of the newly installed styles appear in LyX.
2. Many styles generate errors (repeating messages are about missing/extra/forgotten `$` and `}`).

Using `\usepackage{hyperref}` (reported [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8435/using-bibtex-with-lyx-errors-in-auto-generated-bbl?rq=1)) fixes the problem for some styles, but not all.

(Related question: [Some styles work in Lyx's BibTeX Generated Bibliography, others don't](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65135/some-styles-work-in-lyxs-bibtex-generated-bibliography-others-dont))

### Sample error messages

#### xplain

```
 \authorindexentries
                       {various_authors_main_2015}{\do{Various authors@{Various
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

#### IEEEtranM

```
 ...requires the use of the mciteplus package.}
                                                  \fi
This bibstyle requires the use of the mciteplus package.
```

However, it is installed under the `texlive-latex-extra` umbrella.

#### unsrtnat

```
 ...index.php?title=Main_Page&oldid=647785249}
                                                  .
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
```

Comment: This might not be a LyX thing. Different styles provide different pitfalls. Try it with usual LaTeX, you will get the same problems.

Comment: What's a field named `journal` doing in an entry of type `@misc`? I wouldn't go as far as calling this entry well-formatted.

Comment: Doesn't the linked questions answer also answer this one? Where do you see differences?

Comment: @Johannes_B, I tried without ampersands and it didn't change anything.

Comment: @Mico, I removed the journal entry and no change for the styles I tested.

Comment: The answer by Scott answers this question here as well: different styles have different fields and react differently, something i jokingly described as different styles providing different pitfalls. Done. Addendum: Getting the bib cleaned up, maybe for a specific style, solves the issue. @Mico already pointed out one fault.

Comment: Just by the way: I am not sure, but isn't the last line (*note = {...}*)supposed to end with a comma, too? Could be a source of errors as well, I guess.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach - having a comma follow the final field's value is optional, but not required.

Answer (score 1):

(summarizing the comments above)

This issue is not directly related to LyX, but rather to the individual styles.

> Different styles provide different pitfalls.

Best practice would be formatting the BIB file in accordance with the style to be used.

> Getting the bib cleaned up, maybe for a specific style, solves the
>   issue.

However several best-practices are recommended:

- Add `\usepackage{hyperref}` to the LaTeX preamble.
- Specify URLs in the `url` field and not in the `howpublished` field.
- Use escapes for special chracters such as underscore and ampersand.
- Coordinate entries and fields. For example, `journal` shouldn't be a field in a `misc` entry.